# Wordpress - How to get tag_id working with post_type?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Here the code that's working but when I add category_name or tag_id (see below) - it's not working.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'project', 'posts_per_page' => 6 ) );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>   
        <div>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <div style="clear:both; height: 0px; margin: -20px; padding: -20px;">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    <!-- show pagination here -->
    <?php else : ?>

    <!-- show 404 error here -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

Once I add this -

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'project', 'category_name' => 'featured', 'posts_per_page' => 6 ) );
```

OR

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'project', 'tag_id' => 34, 'posts_per_page' => 6 ) );
```

It fails. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

All fixed --

```
<?php
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array(
    'post_type'              => array( 'project' ),
    'posts_per_page'         => '3',
    'order'                  => 'ASC',
    'orderby'                => 'menu_order',
    'tax_query'              => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'         => 'project_category',
            'terms'            => array( 'featured'),
            'field'            => 'slug'
        ),
    ),
);

// The Query
$portfolio_grid_loop = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $portfolio_grid_loop->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $portfolio_grid_loop->have_posts() ) {
        $portfolio_grid_loop->the_post();
        the_content();
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'project' , 'orderby' => 'date' ,  'order' => 'DESC' 
              ,'posts_per_page' => 6,'cat' => '3',  'paged' => query_var('paged'),

); 
$q = new WP_Query($args); //'cat' your category ID
if ( $q->have_posts() ) { 
  while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    $q->the_post();
    // your loop
  }
}
```